# NSNumber numberWithBool changing the value of boolean from plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsnumber

I have a plist file with the a key APICalls of type boolean set to NO. 
I then retrieve this value in my code like this:

```
NSString *destinationPath= [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DefaultSettings.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *defaultPreferences = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:destinationPath];

NSLog(@"SETUP %@", defaultPreferences);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultPreferences];
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *tmp = [data objectForKey:@"user"];;
user.email = [tmp valueForKey:@"email"];
user.userId = [tmp valueForKey:@"id"];
user.username = [tmp valueForKey:@"username"];
user.APICall = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[defaults objectForKey:@"APICalls"]];

NSLog(@"API Call Value: %@", user.APICall);
```

My first log returns :

```
SETUP {
APICalls = 0;
TrackingTimer = 15;
VoiceMessages = 0;
```

}

Showing me the value of APICalls is 0.
But when I log user.APICall, I get

```
API Call Value: 1
```

Also user.APICall is of type NSNumber.

Comment: Just because you register the defaults to a particular value, doesn't mean they haven't been overridden in the user's Preferences folder. Can you `NSLog()` the value of `defaults` as well, before you attempt to access the specific `APICalls` preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `objectForKey:` of `NSUserDefaults` returns a cocoa object - in this case, it is probably an `NSNumber`. When you pass it to `numberWithBool:` method, it treats `nil` as `NO`, and everything else as `YES`.

If `APICalls` is set as a boolean, you can use it directly, like this:

```
user.APICall = [defaults objectForKey:@"APICalls"];
```

If `APICalls` is a number that you would like to re-interpret as a boolean, you can use this line instead:

```
user.APICall = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[[defaults objectForKey:@"APICalls"] intValue] != 0];
```

Comment: or simply check if nil before assignment

Answer (score -3):

Don't forget to call [userDefaults synchronise].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Turns out it was [userDefaults synchronise] as the author is my friend and it did fix his problem. I assumed the author has sufficient intelligence / insn't a child that needs to be guided on every step of the way and can read the synchronise method documentation on apple developer site. Which explains clearly the purpose of the method, so I don't feel like repeating whats already written, nor copying the documentation here.